# Converting np-array from float to complex

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy-array with a float data type, but an extern function needs it with a complex data type. When I use `a.view(np.complex)`, the real values are also used for the complex values, messing up my further calculations, i.e.:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.view(np.complex)
> b = [1+1i, 2+2i, 3+3i]
```

Is there a command such that I get

```
> b = [1+0i, 2+0i, 3+0i]
```

?

Comment: `view` doesnt' work because the `itemsize` for `complex` is 2x the size for `float`.  So it isn't just another way of looking at the same data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use [`astype()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
In [6]: b = a.astype(complex)
In [7]: b
Out[7]: array([ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j,  3.+0.j])

In [8]: b.dtype
Out[8]: dtype('complex128')
```